# how to use Xlinker in cgo? malformed #cgo argument: -(

Tags: gcc, go, cgo

**env:**

gcc3.4.5
go1.3
linux2.6.32
centos4

**problem:**

I want to pass -Xlinker "-(" and -Xlinker "-)" to cgo LDFLAGS, in order to solve static library order problem.

But it seems that cgo does not support this, failed when compile:

```
xxx.go: malformed #cgo argument: -(
```

The cgo directive which sets LDFLAGS in xxx.go:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Xlinker "-(" libyyy.a libzzz.a -lstdc++ -Xlinker "-)"
import "C"
```

**question:**

how to use -Xlinker in cgo?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full option names of `--start-group` and `--end-group` rather than the shorthand version.